# mongoengine.connect - How to connect to another port that is not default?

Tags: python, telegram, mongoengine, robo3t

#### Im doing a python program and I want to connect MongoDB using mongoengine.

Im using a Macbook pro 2016. On the terminal I hit "mongod --port 27018" and it goes ok. Also, Robo 3T shows that the connection works. The problem is when a run "python3 User.py" I get the error :

#### MongoEngineConnectionError: You have not defined a default connection.

```
mongoengine.connect(db="Telegram_User_DataBase", alias="telegramUDB", port=27018)

class User(mongoengine.Document):
    name = mongoengine.StringField()
    last_name = mongoengine.StringField()
    username = mongoengine.StringField()
    telegramID = mongoengine.StringField()
    is_bot = mongoengine.BooleanField()

def newUser(self, name, last_name, username, telegramID, is_bot):
        """Cria um novo usuario e o salva no banco de dados Telegram_User_DataBase"""
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.username = username
        self.telegramID = telegramID
        self.is_bot = is_bot
        self.save() #error goes right here

#testing
user1 = User()
user1.newUser("erick", "giff", "egf", "1234", False)
```

I was expecting that the program would create my database on port 27018, but that didn't happen.
I think maybe Im doing something wrong on the first line, mongoengine.connect(...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple databases, you need to attach your models to the databases using the `meta` class attribute, otherwise they get attached to `alias='default'` by default

e.g:

```
connect(db='test')    # identified by alias `default`
connect(..., alias='telegramUDB')

class User(Document):
    meta = {'db-alias': 'telegramUDB'}
    name = StringField()

class Person(Document):    # implicitly attached to alias=default
    name = StringField()
```

If you only have 1 database, you better not set `alias` when calling connect(), and then you wouldnt have to deal with bd-alias

Check this page for more info: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#multiple-databases